# Spreading/distributing an entity into multiple tables instead of a single on

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, query-optimization, database-optimization

Why would anyone distribute an entity (for example *user*) into multiple tables by doing something like:

```
user(user_id, username)
user_tel(user_id, tel_no)
user_addr(user_id, addr)
user_details(user_id, details)
```

Is there any speed-up bonus you get from this DB design? It's highly counter-intuitive, because it would seem that performing chained joins to retrieve data sounds immeasurably worse than using select projection..

Of course, if one performs other queries by making use only of the user_id and username, that's a speed-up, but is it worth it? So, where is the real advantage and what could be a compatible working scenario that's fit for such a DB design strategy?

**LATER EDIT:** in the details of this post, please assume a complete, unique entity, whose attributes do not vary in quantity (e.g. a car has only one color, not two, a user has only one username/social sec number/matriculation number/home address/email/etc.. that is, we're not dealing with a one to many relation, but with a 1-to-1, completely consistent description of an entity. In the example above, this is just the case where a single table has been "split" into as many tables as non-primary key columns it had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By splitting the user in this way you have exactly 1 row in user per user, which links to 0-n rows each in user_tel, user_details, user_addr

This in turn means that these can be considered optional, and/or each user may have more than one telephone number linked to them.  All in all it's a more adaptable solution than hardcoding it so that users always have up to 1 address, up to 1 telephone number.

The alternative method is to have i.e. `user.telephone1` `user.telephone2` etc., however this methodology goes against 3NF ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form ) - essentially you are introducing a lot of columns to store the same piece of information

**edit**

Based on the additional edit from OP, assuming that each user will have precisely 0 or 1 of each tel, address, details, and **NEVER** any more, then storing those pieces of information in separate tables is overkill.  It would be more sensible to store within a single user table with columns user_id, username, tel_no, addr, details.

If memory serves this is perfectly fine within 3NF though.  You stated this is not about normal form, however if each piece of data is considered directly related to that specific user then it is fine to have it within the table.

If you later expanded the table to have telephone1, telephone2 (for example) then that would violate 1NF.  If you have duplicate fields (i.e. multiple users share an address, which is entirely plausible), then that violates 2NF which in turn violates 3NF

This point about violating 2NF may well be why someone has done this.

Comment: I should have stated that it's not the 3rd normal form that needs to be taken care of, let's suppose this in itself is an entity and if you perform all of those joins, you end up with data that's perfectly 1-to-1 and redundancy free. I do agree, one use could have 0 or 1 tel no, that is NULL. So there's a mechanism in today's RDMSs out there that help dealing with this issue.

Comment: You asked for a scenario for this kind of database design so I gave you one.  I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for at this point by way of response.  If there will always be exactly one piece of data for each field, and no possibility of a second etc, then having the row as a column within the user table would suffice.  A possible rationale could be to have a table of VARCHARs with numeric IDs which are then linked to a user via an n:m join table however situations where that would be advantageous are difficult to suggest.  All in all your question is too vague as to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to edit it a bit and get rid of some vagueness. My initial worries where to find scenarios other than the trivial ones where this approach makes sense. So, if NF3 isn't broken, it's easier and healthier to leave all of the entity attributes in the same table as columns and there's a rare chance of finding a scenario where "fissioning" these entities this way does justify a performance bonus. E.g. is SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM entity costly if entity has many attributes, but none of them is actually logically connected to any other (as to breach the FN3 rule!?). Thnx!

Comment: See my update, it's actually 2NF that is being broken potentially if you don't split those specific pieces of information out.  The address, in my example, is not directly related to each user as multiple users may exist at a given address.  It may or may not be a big deal though, it is hard to advise without specifics as to an intended purpose for these table(s).  This type of splitting can be more costly in some situations, and in others it can be very advantageous, it really depends on the data both in length, volume, and how it's accessed.

Answer (score 1):

The author of this design perhaps thought that storing NULLs could be achieved more efficiently in the "sparse" structure like this, than it would "in-line" in the single table. The idea was probably to store rows such as `(1 , "john", NULL, NULL, NULL)` just as `(1 , "john")` in the `user` table and no rows at all in other tables. For this to work, NULLs must greatly outnumber non-NULLs (and must be "mixed" in just the right way), otherwise this design quickly becomes more expensive.

Also, this could be somewhat beneficial if you'll constantly SELECT *single* columns. By splitting columns into separate tables, you are making them "narrower" from the storage perspective and lower the I/O *in this specific case* (but not in general).

The problems of this design, in my opinion, far outweigh these benefits.